# Same query, different results in php vs phpmyadmin- Why?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get the total actions from each employee in a MySQL database. My script is giving me a significantly lower total than the number in the database for all employees. I am using a SUM function in the query. The query works fine in phpmyadmin, but not in my script. Any ideas why this is happening.

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, SUM(num_actions) as action FROM pro_actions GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY action DESC";
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    $count = 0; // this is the total of all employee actions. which adds up correctly!
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $count += $row['action'];
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo $row['user_id'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row['action'];
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    $result->free();
}
```

When I run this script, employee 1005 has 63 actions. However, when I run this query in phpmyadmin, employee 1005 has 194 actions (which is correct). All employees have fewer actions in the output of the script. The interesting thing is that the $count variable outputs the correct amount, which is the total of all actions... Please help with this glitch.

Comment: Make sure they're both looking at the same database. And fix this echo '</td></td>'; I think you meant echo '</td></tr>';

Comment: Thanks, they are looking at the same. The </td></tr> are fixed. I was trying to consolidate the actual code for easy reading. I don't get why the $count fuctions properly and not the rest of the output.

Comment: So, youre saying that these codes (absolutely the same as here) work correctly when you c/paste them in PMA, but not in your script?

Comment: Actually, both of them work, kinda.I just get an incorrect value in the script whereas, I get the correct value in PMA. Additionally, I have a var $count in the script that echo's out the correct value. And yes, I literally cut and paste the query from one to the other. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, SUM(num_actions) as action FROM pro_actions GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY action DESC";
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    $count = 0; // this is the total of all employee actions. which adds up correctly!
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $count += $row['action'];
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo $row['user_id'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row['action'];
        echo '</td></tr>'; //tag mismatch
    }
    $result->free();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the tr tag was a typo in this post, not the actual script.